# class function(with a while(mysql_fetch_assoc) , in_array, and json_decode() methods ) not working properly inside a foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have this foreach loop

```
foreach($custom_time as $row) {
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row</td>";
    $check_reservation = $reserve->is_reserved($row);
    if($check_reservation == "reserved"){
      echo "<td>Reserved</td>";
    }
    else {
      echo "<td>Available</td>";
    }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Assuming that $custom_time is an array of time from 8:00 am to 10:00 pm. I would be like to display a table here. Next, I have this function inside the $reserve class.

```
public function is_reserved($time_custom_string){
  $array = $this->reserved_time;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($array)){
    if(in_array($time_custom_string , json_decode($row['reserve_time']))) {
      return "reserved";
    }
  }
}
```

Now, $this->reserved_time is a mysql_query result. Assuming that the result is a json_encoded array of 1:00 pm and 2:00 pm. I'm trying to display a table that would show the 1:00 pm and 2:00 pm row in the table as "Reserved", and the rest will be "Available". The problem is that the table is showing "Available" to all its tablerows. I edit the code like this:

```
foreach($custom_time as $row) {
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row</td>";
    $check_reservation = $reserve->is_reserved($row);
    echo "<td>$check_reservation</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

And the function like this:

```
public function is_reserved($time_custom_string){
  $array = $this->reserved_time;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($array)){
    if(in_array($time_custom_string , json_decode($row['reserve_time']))) {
      return "reserved";
    }
    else {
      return "not reserved";
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the table only printed the first row as "Not Reserved". The succeeding tablerows are blank. I'm stuck with this for hours but I still can't see why my code is not working as I expected, I think my code seems right. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` advances the internal pointer until it gets to the last row, at which point it returns `false` (therefore allowing your loop to exit).

Calling it again will just keep on returning `false`.

You can reset it with [`mysql_data_seek`](http://php.net/mysql-data-seek)`($array,0)`

Comment: thanks.. you fixed it. i thought the internal pointer will be resetted to the first row because i used a different variable as the mysql_query result. but it doesn't. my variable is not an object clone, the location of the pointer from the original variable must be different to the location of the one that ive been declaring inside the function